# Using your Grape API from within Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers, ruby-grape, grape-api

Is it a good idea to use already implemented Grape API endpoints from within your Rails Application controllers?

I'm making an application where my Rails Controllers have shared functionality with my API. I've already implemented the API of an application, now I'm implementing the controllers.

So my question is, is there a way to issue a request from a controller to my Grape API endpoint without it going through the internet? If so, is it a good idea or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call Grape endpoints from your Rails controllers instead make Ajax calls to your Grape endpoints and consume the API from the web/mobile front end. It is a good idea to have a single point of entry to your application rather than exposing Grape routes as well as Rails routes.